# Why can't Delphi 10.3.2 find Posix.Locale.pas unit for an Android application?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, nexus-7, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm new to doing cross-platform development with Delphi and I thought I'd give it a go. I have a Nexus 7, up-to-date and have the USB debugging enabled on it, etc.

Right now, I just want to test out an empty form and I get a compile time error Unit 'Posix.Locale' not found. The source file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\source\rtl\posix" is present so I'm unsure why the compiler can't find it.

I don't see any obvious PATH settings under Environmental Variables.

Any ideas?

Comment: The compiler is looking for `Posix.Locale.dcu`, either as a standalone file or inside a package referenced by your project.  Clearly it is not finding either one. Are you sure that `Posix.Locale` is supposed to exist for Android? What are the exact steps you performed to create and configure your project?

Comment: This is what I did:

1) New Multi-Device Application
2) Blank Application
3) Save Project
4) Set Android as startup project
5) Compile 

Errors:

Unit 'Posix.Locale' not found.
Unit 'Posix.Locale' is used by 'System.SysUtils'
Unit 'System.SysUtils' is used by 'System.StartUpCopy'

Comment: Locale routines for Android are through the Locale class, which is imported as JLocale in Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes

Answer (score 1):

So this ended up being a corrupted install. I orginally installed from the web installer which Embarcardero mentioned is more problematic than the ISO install. So I uninstalled, did the recommended post-uninstall cleanup and then reinstalled from the ISO. Also, they provided a list of several things to do to clean up after uninstalling 10.3.2.

========================MANUAL UNINSTALL 10.3========================
Launch the License Manager from the bin folder (by default "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\LicenseManager.exe") and

delete any trial or beta (Test Field) license that you can find. Check it under “License Details” in the center column.

Under your Control Panel's Program and Features Add/Remove Program uninstall the following entries:
-RAD Studio 10.3 version 20.0

Please follow these instructions to remove any leftover files:

1. If Windows 32-bit, remove the C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0 directory (or the custom folder you had used).
2. If Windows 64-bit, remove the C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0 directory (or the custom folder you had used).
3. Remove the C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0 directory
4. Remove the C:\ProgramData\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0 directory.
5. Remove the %APPDATA%\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0 directory.
6. Remove the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0 registry key
7. If Windows 32-bit, remove the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0 registry key
8. If Windows 64-bit, remove the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0
9. If Windows 32-bit, remove the following files from C:\Windows\System32:
   a. BDEAdmin.*
   b. CC32*.DLL
   c. Midas.*
   d. Xerces*.DLL
10. If Windows 64-bit, remove the following files from C:\Windows\SysWOW64:
    a. BDEAdmin.*
    b. CC32*.DLL
    c. Midas.*
    d. Xerces*.DLL

Please reinstall software via ISO:

RAD Studio, Delphi, C++Builder 10.3.2 ISO

Also, manually delete the slip files in C:\programdata\embarcadero folder (this is a hidden folder which you need to enable first). Then shut down and re-install using the ISO